# Black Rectangle when exporting chart to PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, itext

I have a little problem, when i'd like export my chart to a new PDF file. After the export if I open the PDF I see the chart, but under this chart image I see a black rectangle too.
I think the problem is the size, but I don't know what size need I to change.

```
Document PDF_dokumentum2 = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 50, 25);
PdfWriter writer2 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDF_dokumentum2, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\my\Desktop\asd.pdf", FileMode.Create));
PDF_dokumentum2.Open();
Bitmap asd = new Bitmap(650,600);
Kereslet_Chart.DrawToBitmap(asd, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0,0,700,600));
iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(asd, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
pdfImage.ScaleToFit(600,400);
pdfImage.Alignment = 1;           
PDF_dokumentum2.Add(pdfImage);
PDF_dokumentum2.Close();
```

So and the result:[image: RESULT]

Tanks.

Comment: Ignoring the PDF for now, if you save the image to disk does it have a black box at the bottom of it?

Comment: No. If I save it just like an image, it hasn't got black box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. The `Bitmap` was too big.

Comment: You must just decrease the size of your `Bitmap`.